# How to enable HTML view by default in KMail?

Tags: kmail

Kmail shows mails in text format by default. It does it so strictly that even in the case of HTML-only mails, it shows rather the HTML source, as to show the mail in HTML format.

Although it shows an option in the message window to see the mail in HTML, it must be clicked for every mail.

I want KMail to show the mails in HTML format as default, without the need of any additional clicks. So, what I want is the most trivial thing in every mail client since a decade.

I didn't find any option in the settings for that.

Is it somehow possible? If it was not implemented, why? Yes, I know it cites security reasons, but I can't imagine what security problems could it have to render a pure HTML (without any JS, external images, etc).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is:

Go to `Settings` -> `Configure KMail...` -> `Security` -> `Reading` and tick `Prefer HTML to plain text` in the `HTML Messages` box.

You might have to restart KMail for it to take effect.

Comment: Once I updated the security settings to show html over plain text I did not have to resart Kmail.

Comment: From some strange reason I still get "View HTML" prompt with every message

Comment: @MichalPolovka I don't use KDE some years ago, but sometimes I still awake at night, whining about its sad fate :-(